# Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

The question is:

A. Calculate the Fourier transform of the function

$$ f(x) = a^2-x^2, |x| < a$$
$$ f(x) = 0, |x| > a$$

where $a \ge 0$

B. Hence, deduce

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^3}\,\Bbb dx = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

HINT: Start from inverse Fourier transform and note that $f(0) = a^2$.

First time using Math Stack Exchange so I appreciate any patience for me with the MathJax notation! Essentially I'm struggling on part B of the question. What I got for part A was:
$$4\left(\frac{\sin(ua)-au\cos(ua)}{u^3}\right)$$

(Don't know if that's right, but took the limits from $-a$ to $a$, since everywhere else it will equal 0.)

When I try deducing the integral, I keep getting it equal to $a^2(\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Suggest to write the Laplace transform pair down, as in $\int dt e^{-s t} f(t) = \tilde{f}(s)$, then ask yourself if there's a way to manipulate this pair so the integral you want is on one side, and the solution you want is on the other. Seems you're absurdly close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be the function defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}a^2-x^2&,|x|\le a\\\\0&,|x|>a\end{cases}$$

The Fourier Transform of $f$ is then

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(u)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{iux}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-a}^{a} (a^2-x^2)e^{iux}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{4\sin(au)-4au\cos(au)}{u^3} 
\end{align}$$

From the Inverse Fourier Transform, we have

$$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{4\sin(au)-4au\cos(au)}{u^3}e^{-iux}\,du\tag1$$

Now, enforcing the substitution $au\mapsto u$, we see that for $|x|\le a$

$$(a^2-x^2)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty 4a^2\frac{\sin(u)-x\cos(u)}{u}e^{-iux/a}\,du\tag2$$

Setting $x=0$ in $(2)$, we find that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)-u\cos(u)}{u^3}\,du=\frac\pi2\tag3$$

Exploiting the even symmetry of the integrand in $(3)$, we arrive at the coveted result

$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(u)-u\cos(u)}{u^3}\,du=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: That au ↦ u substitution was really smart, didn't think of that, thank you so much! I have only just started learning Fourier transform and from learning integration in high school, I didn't think to substitute in this scenario. What was your thinking process in why you thought you had to substitute? Thanks again for the step by step method, helped a lot!

Comment: @BlueHoodie You're welcome.  My pleasure.  We were asked to show that a certain integral was equal to $\pi/4$.  Note that the arguments in the sine and cosine functions of the integrand did not have the parameter $a$.  So, this prompted me to scale the arguments accordingly.